# Could I send struct array into other function? C language

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm recently writing a program that would use struct and I met a problem. 
This program will define a struct, called "polynomial" and declare a struct array called "polynomial term[]" in main(). I want to pass this struct array into "StorePoly()", but I got some erros. Many thanks first if anyone could help me.

p.s. The reason why I declare the struct array in main() is because I don't want the amount of index of the array be fixed. the following is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int coef;
    int expon;
}polynomial;

int StorePoly(struct polynomial);


int main(void)
{
    int NumberofTermsA = 0;
    int Memory = 100;

    polynomial term[Memory];

    StorePoly(polynomial term);
    return 0;
}


int StorePoly(struct polynomial term[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        term[i].coef = i;
        term[i].expon = i*2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```
StorePoly(polynomial term);
```

to

```
StorePoly(term);
```

and change the function declaration

```
int StorePoly(struct polynomial term[])
```

to

```
int StorePoly(polynomial term[])
```

and also the prototype

```
int StorePoly(struct polynomial);
```

to

```
int StorePoly(polynomial[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing both the datatype and variable in

StorePoly(polynomial term);

change it to

StorePoly(term);

Answer (score 0):

The function should be declared like

```
void StorePoly(struct polynomial[], int n );
```

and called like for example

```
StorePoly(term, 5 );
```